# Programmatic interaction with gdbserver

Tags: gdb, client, protocols, remote-debugging

The gdbserver program allows for the remote debugging of programs. Typically, a local copy of gdb is used to interact with the remote gdbserver instance, and the program running under that remote gdbserver.

My question is: Are there client implementations of the [gdb remote serial protocol](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb_34.html#SEC721) (RSP) that allow programs other than gdb to interact with the gdbserver program?

This document discusses the implementation of an [RSP server](http://www.embecosm.com/appnotes/ean4/html/), but it is the client side I am primarily interested in. This [implementation](http://github.com/blitz/gdb-remote/tree/master) supports client and server, but is implemented in common lisp, and is not yet a mature library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any clients of the GDB protocol.

Why would you want one?

For simple tasks (starting; stopping; examining memory addresses) you can write one from scratch pretty quickly.

For complicated tasks (unwinding stack, examining variables, etc.) you'd have to re-implement significant parts of GDB; and that should probably not be attempted without a very good reason.

Also note that GDB/gdbserver protocol is constantly evolving; there are provisions to let newer GDB deal with older gdbserver, but I am not sure if the reverse is also true.

Comment: All good points; I have decided to control a local GDB via the GDB machine interface, and let the local GDB interact with the remote gdbserver

Answer (score 5):

The remote gdb protocol is fully documented in the gdb manual, which is available online at
http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb_toc.html

You have gdb to look at as a working example -- this should be enough to allow you to write a client to control gdbserver over the serial protocol.   ;-)

Comment: The link is broken.